# Retrieving a dataset object from DataAccessLayer.cs to a gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I have a regular aspx.cs file which contains a gridview control, then there is a `DataManager.cs` class object and a `DataAccessLayer.cs` class object (which connects to the database and fills a dataset).

How can I retrieve the dataset records from the `DataAccessLayer.cs` file into the `DataManager.cs` file and then into the `aspx.cs` file (having a brain fart)?

```
eCustomer.GetCustomers(oCustomer);  
gvCustomers.Datasource = dsCustomers  

eCustomer.CustomerManager(oCust);  

eCustomer.CustomerDataAccessLayer(oCust);  
// Dataset object is here//
```

Comment: Please write a code that compiles. Consider using gvCustomers.DataBind()

Comment: Please provide GridView binding code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for demonstration.

```
    GridView1.DataSource = MyDataSet;
    //Other option      GridView1.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables["MyTableName"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
```